# Fusion auth app failing to start with limited logging, is there a config to change the logging from INFO to DEBUG?

Tags: fusionauth

We did have fusionauth up and running in our automated test environment. However now it is failing to start.
In our other environments we have the exact same setup running.
Usually my go-to is the fusionauthapp_stdout logs. Whats strange however is that the logs seem to stop being emitted at an early startup stage.

In the environment(s) that are working correctly the logs look like I expect for a normal startup as shown in the first example:

#### Working environment:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\administrator\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Users\administrator\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\administrator\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Users\administrator\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\..\..\java\jre1.8.0_171"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Users\administrator\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\administrator\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:11.414 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Loading FusionAuth configuration file [C:\Users\administrator\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\..\..\config\fusionauth.properties]
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:11.478 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Dynamically set property [fusionauth-app.public-url] set to [http://192.168.XX.XX:XXXX]
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:11.479 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - FusionAuth Runtime Mode [Production]
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:11.599 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Loading FusionAuth configuration file [C:\Users\administrator\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\..\..\config\fusionauth.properties]
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:11.664 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Dynamically set property [fusionauth-app.public-url] set to [http://192.168.XX.XX:XXXX
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:11.665 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - FusionAuth Runtime Mode [Production]
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:11.925 AM INFO  com.inversoft.maintenance.db.JDBCMaintenanceModeDatabaseService - Database Version [1.3.1]
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:11.927 AM INFO  com.inversoft.maintenance.db.JDBCMaintenanceModeDatabaseService - Latest Migration Version [1.1.0]
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:11.929 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.app.maintenance.FusionAuthMaintenanceModeWorkflow - Determine database status : ACTIVE
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:12.113 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.app.maintenance.FusionAuthMaintenanceModeWorkflow - Determine search status : ACTIVE]
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:12.115 AM INFO  org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.PrimeServletContextListener - Initializing Prime
Jul 10, 2019 10:41:12.118 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.app.guice.FusionAuthModule - 


--------- Starting FusionAuth version [1.3.1] -------
logs continue
```

#### Failing environment:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\..\..\java\jre1.8.0_171"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Jul 10, 2019 10:57:41.944 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Loading FusionAuth configuration file [C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\..\..\config\fusionauth.properties]
Jul 10, 2019 10:57:41.993 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Dynamically set property [fusionauth-app.public-url] set to [http://192.168.XX.XX:XXXX]
Jul 10, 2019 10:57:41.994 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - FusionAuth Runtime Mode [Production]
Jul 10, 2019 10:57:42.164 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Loading FusionAuth configuration file [C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\..\..\config\fusionauth.properties]
Jul 10, 2019 10:57:42.208 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Dynamically set property [fusionauth-app.public-url] set to [http://192.168.XX.XX:XXXX]
Jul 10, 2019 10:57:42.209 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - FusionAuth Runtime Mode [Production]
```

The logs stop abruptly after the properties configuration...

I appreciate this is probably an issue with out environment however without the logs I am pretty stumped.

Currently the log level is INFO. Is there anyway to set the log level lower, for example to DEBUG so I can understand further whats happening?

I have already tried restarting the server.

Restarted both the fusion auth app and fusion auth search services

Tried running the fusion auth app and fusion auth search manually i.e. not as a service

### 12/07/2019 Updated logs with logback.xml

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\..\..\java\jre1.8.0_171"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
08:03:37,104 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
08:03:37,104 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
08:03:37,105 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/fusionauth/fusionauth-app/web/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
08:03:37,105 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
08:03:37,105 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/fusionauth/fusionauth-app/web/WEB-INF/lib/fusionauth-app-1.3.1.jar!/logback.xml]
08:03:37,105 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/C:/fusionauth/fusionauth-app/web/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
08:03:37,140 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
08:03:37,147 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeFilter scanning period to 1 minutes
08:03:37,147 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\web\WEB-INF\classes\logback.xml]] every 60 seconds. 
08:03:37,147 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
08:03:37,152 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
08:03:37,155 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
08:03:37,170 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
08:03:37,204 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [io.fusionauth] to DEBUG
08:03:37,204 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [io.fusionauth] to false
08:03:37,204 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[io.fusionauth]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.primeframework] to DEBUG
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.primeframework] to false
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.primeframework]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.inversoft.migration] to DEBUG
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.inversoft.migration] to false
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[com.inversoft.migration]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.inversoft.maintenance] to DEBUG
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.inversoft.maintenance] to false
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[com.inversoft.maintenance]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser] to DEBUG
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser] to false
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig] to DEBUG
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig] to false
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig] to DEBUG
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig] to false
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer] to DEBUG
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer] to false
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient] to DEBUG
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient] to false
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
08:03:37,205 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
08:03:37,206 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@18a29fef - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

Jul 12, 2019 8:03:37.218 AM DEBUG org.primeframework.mvc.guice.GuiceBootstrap - Initializing Guice
Jul 12, 2019 8:03:37.800 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Loading FusionAuth configuration file [C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\..\..\config\fusionauth.properties]
Jul 12, 2019 8:03:37.840 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Dynamically set property [fusionauth-app.public-url] set to [http://192.168.XX.XX:XXXX]
Jul 12, 2019 8:03:37.841 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - FusionAuth Runtime Mode [Production]
Jul 12, 2019 8:03:37.965 AM DEBUG org.primeframework.mvc.guice.GuiceBootstrap - Initializing Guice
Jul 12, 2019 8:03:37.969 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Loading FusionAuth configuration file [C:\fusionauth\fusionauth-app\apache-tomcat\..\..\config\fusionauth.properties]
Jul 12, 2019 8:03:38.008 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - Dynamically set property [fusionauth-app.public-url] set to [http://192.168.XX.XX:XXXX]
Jul 12, 2019 8:03:38.009 AM INFO  io.fusionauth.api.configuration.PropertiesFileFusionAuthConfiguration - FusionAuth Runtime Mode [Production]
Jul 12, 2019 8:03:38.061 AM DEBUG com.inversoft.maintenance.db.JDBCMaintenanceModeDatabaseService - Connection established to [192.168.XX.XX:XXXX]
```

Comment: The only difference I see is the location of FusionAuth, `C:\fusionauth`  vs `C:\Users\administrator\fusionauth`. Could be a file permissions issue?   If you want to try to enable `DEBUG` to see if that provides additional information, place a `logback.xml` file in `fusionauth\fusionauth-app\web\WEB-INF\classes` and then restart the service. Here is an example configuration with `DEBUG` enabled. https://gist.github.com/robotdan/422904ddf9381233b0ac73654fd8d243

Comment: @robotdan Thankyou for your response and suggestions, I will double check the file permissions and create the logback.xml file and see what I can diagnose from the logs and will get back to you

Comment: @robotdan I dropped the logback.xml file into the directory, this did output more logs however they were not helpful and still seem to reach the same point then just stop outputting any further. I have updated the question with new log output. I also checked file permissions. The root fusionauth folder and children have full permissions as expected

Comment: @robotdan we have spotted the issue! The incorrect port number had been specified for the database. We assume this resulted in application start up process just hanging due to trying to connect to the DB.
Thank you for all your help

Comment: @robotdan perhaps you can move your comment to an answer so i can mark that as answered as it solved my initial query of logger level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the log level during startup, you can perform the following steps:

Place a `logback.xml` file in `fusionauth\fusionauth-app\web\WEB-INF\classes` and then restart the service.

Here is an example configuration with DEBUG enabled.

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{"MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss.SSS a"} %-5level %logger{75} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- DEBUG enabled -->
  <logger name="io.fusionauth" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.primeframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="com.inversoft.migration" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <logger name="com.inversoft.maintenance" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <!-- Kafka logging is chatty -->
  <logger name="org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

https://gist.github.com/robotdan/422904ddf9381233b0ac73654fd8d243

Comment: Can you show how to do this with Docker/Helm chart instead ?

Comment: There is not a built in mechanism special to docker/helm. You could mount the example above into the correct location. Generally speaking there should be adequate output of we are failing to start.

Comment: May I suggest a flag/environment variable that can be used to configure Helm/Docker easily for DEBUG? For example, in Spring Boot application we can set `LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT=DEBUG` to get `DEBUG` level on root logger quickly before using detailed logging configuration. If this is acceptable I can re-post this request as issue in relevant github repository.

Comment: Thanks @HendyIrawan - yes can you please open a GitHub feature? https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues

Comment: Thanks! sure: https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/559